# How can I configure Lenovo S540 touchpad on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo thinkpad S540. The problem is I have a touchpad all in one click (no seperate buttons) and the standard configuration is screwed up.

It's almost impossible to right click and sometimes when I left click is does right click. So I have to use a mouse otherwise I'm forced to use windows where the settings are just ok.

Also I cannot create a new document on `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` so I'm forced to adjust one of the files.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you tried editing these files in directory /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d with sudo?
Edit: like sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/<somefile>

Comment: Yes I have and the terminal tells me i'm not the root.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf as follows. Moreoevr, I used xSwipe to add some "swipe" functionalities.

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" 
    # disable synaptics driver pointer acceleration
    Option "Protocol" "event"
    Option "SHMConfig" "on"
        Option "MinSpeed" "1"
        Option "MaxSpeed" "1"
        # tweak the X-server pointer acceleration
        Option "AccelerationProfile" "2"
        Option "AdaptiveDeceleration" "16"
        Option "ConstantDeceleration" "16"
        Option "VelocityScale" "32"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"     # left click with one finger tap
        Option "TapButton2" "3"     # right click with two finger tap
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#EndSection

# 
#Section "InputClass"
#        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
#        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
#        MatchOS "Linux"
#        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
#        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on
# non-synaptics clickpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
#Section "InputClass"
#        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
#        MatchDriver "synaptics"
#        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "60% 0 0 5% 40% 60% 0 5%"
#       To disable the bottom edge area so the buttons only work as buttons,
#       not for movement, set the AreaBottomEdge
#        Option "AreaTopEdge" "4%"
#EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```